# Mean time spent in transient states /inverse of (I-P)

Tags: markov-chains

For transient states $i$ and $j$ , let $s_{ij}$ denote the expected number of time periods that the Markov chain is in state $j$, given that it starts in state $i$. Let

$\delta_{i,j}=
\begin{cases}
1,&\text{when $i=j\quad$ and}\\
0,& \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$

Condition of the initial transition to obtain:

$s_{ij}=\delta_{i,j}+\sum P_{ik}s_{kj}$

Let $S$ denote the matrix of values $s_{ij},\text{for }i,j=1,2,\cdots,t$

In matrix notation,
$S=I+PS$,
$S=(I-P)^{-1}$
where $P$ specifies the transition probabilities from transient states into transient states.

Can someone show me how to prove the existence of the inverse of $(I-P)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{(I-P)x=0}$, which implies $\mathbf{x-Px=0}\Rightarrow\mathbf{x=Px}$. But it is an iterative equation meaning that $$\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{P}^n\mathbf{x}\tag{1}$$

Since $\mathbf{P}^n\to\mathbf{0}$, it means also $\mathbf{P}^n\mathbf{x}\to\mathbf{0}$. From $(1)$, it implies $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$. So $\mathbf{I-P}$ is invertible.

It is also worth adding that
$$(\mathbf{I-P})(\mathbf{I+P}+\mathbf{P}^2+\cdots+\mathbf{P}^n)=\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{P}^{n+1}$$
again, as $n\to\infty$ it becomes:
$$(\mathbf{I-P})(\mathbf{I+P}+\mathbf{P}^2+\cdots)=\mathbf{I}$$
Hence,
$$(\mathbf{I-P})^{-1}=(\mathbf{I+P}+\mathbf{P}^2+\cdots)$$

Comment: How can I get P^n→0? Can you prove that?

Comment: @plaschik Indeed, we need the Markov chain have at least one absorbing state for that to hold. In such case, beginning from any transient state, the Markov chain will eventually reach an absorbing state and equivalently the probability of not absorbing after $n$ steps (which is the probability of being in a transient state) will monotonically reduce and tends to zero.